# Java8/JBoss7 - EJB Invocation failed

Tags: java, java-8, jboss, wildfly

I'm converting a `Jboss5` App to `JBoss7` and I've been running into issues using `EJBs.`

There seems to be an authorization exception whenever a method is called from a local bean. How has the `EJB` structure for `Java 8` apps changed from EAP 5 to 7?

**Error**

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component ManagerLocal for method public abstract java.util.List com.data.manager.local.ManagerLocal.searchRequests(...): javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: WFLYEJB0364: Invocation on method: public abstract java.util.List com.data.manager.local.ManagerLocal.searchRequests(...) of bean: ManagerLocal is not allowed
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.AuthorizationInterceptor.processInvocation(AuthorizationInterceptor.java:134)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:632)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at com.data.manager.local.ManagerLocal$$$view153.searchRequests(Unknown Source)
    at com.web.resource.RequestResource.searchRequests(RequestResource.java:397)
    at com.trigger.handler.TriggerHandler.execute(TriggerHandler.java:43)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
```

**Local Bean**

```
@Local
@PermitAll()
public interface ManagerLocal {
    @PermitAll()
    public List<Request> searchRequests(...);

}
```

**Resource**

```
@Path("/request")
public class RequestResource {
    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestResource.class);
    private static final String SLASH = "/";

    public RequestResource(){

    }
    @PermitAll()
    private ManagerLocal getRequestManager()
    {
        ManagerLocal manager = null;

        try
        {
            manager = LookupUtil.lookup(ManagerLocal.class);
        }
        catch (NamingException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't get an instance of manager bean", e);
        }

        return manager;
    }

    @PermitAll()
    public List<Request> searchRequests(...){
        return getRequestManager().searchRequests(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `@PermitAll()` on the `ManagerLocal` implementation?

Comment: @k5_ yes I've updated the code accordingly. Still getting the error.

Comment: I meant the implementation not the interface

Comment: @k5_ yes the call for `getRequestManager` is `@PermitAll()`